# Attach dynamic text to models

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

If I want to display different text contents in real time to different models, i.e. attaching dynamic text to models, how should I do?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13685/attach-dynamic-text-to-models/) by [winston](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1084/winston/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 449 on 2016-06-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Check out [this](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12731/is-there-a-way-to-make-gazebo-display-the-models-name/) answer.

Take a look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rsftOnKI4q4) video of a plugin which displays floating model names. The source code is [here](https://bitbucket.org/chapulina/gazebo_plugins/src/default/FloatingModelNames/). You can try to modify it to display the information you want.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0